# How to add volume to a ec2 instance on aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Created an ec2 instance with default `Root Volume Type`. That's just 8 GB.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G   25M  1.6G   2% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.3G  439M  95% /
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs           1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/113
```

Now the instace is full used like above. Want to add volume size, created an EBS volume, how to attach it to the instance without deleting the original data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below aws documentation will answer your questions

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/expand-linux-partition.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1. Add another volume.**
Go to AWS Console -> EC2 -> Elastic Block Store -> Volumes. Create a volume, attach it to your instance. From that point on you should see the new volume from your instance with`lsblk`. Make a file system with `mk2fs` or whatever and mount with `mount`.

**Option 2. Extend your current volume.**
Stop the instance, make a volume snapshot, create a new volume of the required size from that snapshot, detach old volume from the instance, attach the new volume. Make sure you're creating volume in the same availability zone that your EC2 instance is in. Start your instance. In most cases that's enough. If you file system was not resized automatically, use `resize2fs` to do it manually.